# fixer triggered by nonmatching case in directory "./tests/" and namespace "Tests"

Tags: symfony, php-cs-fixer

In symfony 3 tests are in the directory ./tests/ (not in ./src/ anymore). But the test files use the namespace Tests... (first letter uppercase), which is also configured in composer.json (as psr-4 loader).

But this difference in upper and lower case seems to violate PSR0. At least php-cs-fixer reports a failure of fixer "psr0" and wants to call the namespace "tests\..." (all lowercase).

- Does anybody know why the directory name is tests but the namespace is Tests?
- Does this really violate a valid PSR or is PSR-0 outdated by PSR-4 and this is now valid?
- In case it is valid: Is there an other fixer or can I configure this fixer (do not understand this in the source) or ...?
  I'd prefer to not disable the fixer because the subdirectory name and the file name "MUST match the case" of the corresponding namespace and class.

---

Infos:

symfony: v3.1.2
PHP CS Fixer: version 1.11.5
running php-cs-fixer: `php php-cs-fixer --level=symfony tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php`

---

Links:

psr-4: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#2-specification
fixer psr0: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/1.11/Symfony/CS/Fixer/PSR0/Psr0Fixer.php